# Draw rectangular nodes defined by opposing corner coordinates with vertically centered text

Tags: tikz-pgf, vertical-alignment, positioning, nodes

I've got some coordinates in a [tikz](/questions/tagged/tikz)-picture and I'd like to draw some rectangles defined by two opposing corner coordinates. The seemingly easiest way to do that I found with this answer: [**Placing a rectangular node in tikz by specifying two opposing corners**](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/250191/36835). However I can't manage to get the text **vertically and horizontally centered** within the drawn rectangle.

I fiddled around with various anchor points within my `tikzset{...}` and the `text centered` property, but they all seem to only affect the box, not the text.

---

### MWE:

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{fit}
\tikzset{
    block/.style 2 args = {
        draw, line width = 1pt, inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt,
        fit=(#1) (#2),}
}


\begin{document}

    \begin{tikzpicture}[x=1mm,y=1mm]

    \draw[step=1cm,gray,very thin] (-10,-10) grid (70,70);

    \coordinate[](0_r1) at (0,22.5);
    \coordinate[](0_r2) at (0,42);
    \coordinate[](0_r3) at (0,49);

    \coordinate[](b1_r2) at (14.4,42);
    \coordinate[](b1_r3) at (14.4,49);
    \coordinate[](b1_r4) at (14.4,59,0);

    \node[block={0_r1}{b1_r2}] {$R_{mki1}$};
    \node[block={0_r2}{b1_r3}] {$R_{mr1}$};
    \node[block={0_r3}{b1_r4}] {$R_{mko1}$};

    \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

I'm open for other ways for drawing the rectangles, but they need to be defined by predefined coordinates. Also I need to vary the line styles and filling of every rectangle, so I'd like to keep the `tikzset` as simple as possible and define this properties outside.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a known issue, and it has been treated before<sup>1</sup> but it could be a problem in the code for the `fit` library.<sup>2</sup>

However you can use the solution found in one of those questions and use the label instead.

I also think it's easier if you create a new command for placing your nodes which reduces 3 lines of code for one node, to one line of code, using the following syntax:

```
\fnode[optional]{bottom left coord}{top right coord}{text}
```

### Output

[image: figure 1]

### Code

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{fit}

\tikzset{
    block/.style 2 args = {
        draw, line width=1pt, inner sep=0, outer sep=0,
        fit=(#1) (#2)}
}

\newcommand{\fnode}[4][]{
    \coordinate (bottom left) at (#2);
    \coordinate (top right) at (#3);
     \node[block={bottom left}{top right}, #1, label=center:#4] {};
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[x=1mm,y=1mm]

\draw[step=1cm,gray,very thin] (-10,-10) grid (70,70);

\fnode{0,22.5}{14.4,42}{$R_{mki1}$}
\fnode{0,42}{14.4,49}{$R_{mr1}$}
\fnode{0,49}{14.4,59}{$R_{mko1}$}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

---

<sup>1: [node positioned by fit: how to center a node text?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/210713/4778)</sup>
<sup>2: [Wrong vertical text position with Tikz](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/79172/4778)</sup>

Answer (score 3):

This works perfect as long as your text doesn't get too long.

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=6mm]{standalone}

\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[x=1mm, y=1mm]
    \coordinate[](0_r1) at (0,22.5);
    \coordinate[](0_r2) at (0,42);
    \coordinate[](0_r3) at (0,49);

    \coordinate[](b1_r2) at (14.4,42);
    \coordinate[](b1_r3) at (14.4,49);
    \coordinate[](b1_r4) at (14.4,59,0);

    \draw (0_r1) rectangle (b1_r2) node [pos=.5] {$R_{mki1}$};
    \draw (0_r2) rectangle (b1_r3) node [pos=.5] {$R_{mr1}$};
    \draw (0_r3) rectangle (b1_r4) node [pos=.5] {$R_{mko1}$};
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: rendered image]

Comment: equally good solution, in some case probably even more versatile! The other answer offers more explanations though, Thank you!